# multiple checkboxes php code help - posting to a text file

Tags: php, checkbox

When my multiple checkbox form field submits it just says "Array" in the response field

Heres the code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="drive[]" value="4wd" />4 Wheel Drive
<input type="checkbox" name="drive[]" value="allwd" />All Wheel Drive
<input type="checkbox" name="drive[]" value="rearwd" />Rear Wheel Drive
<input type="checkbox" name="drive[]" value="frontwd" />Front Wheel Drive
```

And the PHP code is:

```
$drive=$_POST['drive'];
$drivestring=implode(",",$_POST['drive']);
```

And then some other PHP code is in there that already works to make the text file, I just need the $drivestring to make a list of the checked values separated by commas.

Comment: Unrelated - what's the difference between AWD and 4WD?

Comment: Aside from the missing `)`, why isn't this working? `$drivestring` should contain the string you want.

Comment: Have you tried a print_r($drive); ? This will show if there is anything in the array.

Comment: @savagenoob if $drive outputs "array" then it should have something in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine - you'll need to put a closing bracket on the end of `$drivestring=implode(",",$_POST['drive'];` but I figure that's just a typo.

Are you sure you're outputting `$drivestring` and not `$drive`?

Comment: yeah, the ) missing is just a type in here, its correct in my code.  I am outputting $drivestring, should i be outputting $drive?

Comment: No - it should be just fine. If codepad.org was working I'd test it =/

Comment: Yeah its working now, the code above works fine, its just some other weird thing in the rest of the code.  Thanks everyone for their help